# Unable to find type definitions when using typescript 3.0.1 project refferences

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I initially had following project structure (monorepo)

```
_app/
_firebase/
_types/
tsconfig.json
```

Here, tsconfig at root level was used for `_app` and `_firebase` typescript projects. `_types` is a folder containing files like `models.ts`, `store.ts` etc... these files just define different interfaces.

I was able to use these interfaces without importing / exporting anything in both `_app` and `_firebase` projects before with no isssues.

I made a change to use typescripts v3 project refferences, so my app structure now looks like this

```
_app/
  tsconfig.json
_firebase/
  tsconfig.json
_types/
tsconfig.json
```

Root level `tsconfig.json` has following contents

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true
  },
  "references": [
    { 
      "path": "_app" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Other configs just have simple options like `outDir`, `target`, `lib` etc...

Now if I use interfaces from `_types` folder anywhere in `_app` or `_firebase` I get errors like

> [ts] Cannot find name 'IInventoryModel'.

Is there any way I can preserve previous functionality where I was able to use these interfaces without explicit exports / imports while still taking advantage of new projects refferences feature?

**EDIT:** here is example of tsconfig for `_app`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2016"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2** interfaces inside `_types` folder are declared like this i.e. `_types/models.ts` has

```
interface ICharacterModel { /* ... */ }

interface IInventoryModel { /* ... */ }

// etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `_types` needs its own `tsconfig.json` and `_app` needs to reference it.  Then, based on [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#what-is-a-project-reference), it looks like the magic step is to set an `outFile` on `_types`.  The following configuration is working for me:

```
// _app/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2016"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../_types"
    }
  ]
}

// _types/tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "outFile": "types.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this going, could you clarify / give repo example of where this is working for you by any chance?

I created tsconfig.json inside `_types` folder, added `outFile` and refferenced it from `_app` as you mentioned, but interfaces used in `_app` that are defined in `_types` still throw that error.

Do I keep tsconfig.json file that is located in the root of my project as well?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/mattmccutchen/stackoverflow-51799200 .  Run `tsc -b .` in the `_app` directory.  It shouldn't matter whether you keep the `tsconfig.json` in the root directory.

Comment: Completely forgot about `--build`, it works now :) I can see few bugs however i.e. `tsc -b --skipLibCheck` results in `skipLibCheck` is not a file error, so I guess I'll give more time to project refferences to mature.

VSCode doesn't seem to support it at the moment as well

Comment: Try `tsc --skipLibCheck -b .` .  VS Code is working fine for me; make sure the TypeScript version displays as 3.0.1 in the status bar.

Comment: It is indeed 3.0.1, and I checked with your repo `IInventoryModel` errors with `[ts] Cannot find name 'IInventoryModel'.` for me :/ Is there any particular setting that needs to be enabled for vs code here?

Comment: VSCode works for me _after_ I run `tsc -b .` in the `_app` directory.  This is a [known limitation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#caveats-for-project-references).  If you are still having trouble, consider filing a bug against VSCode and they will hopefully know how to investigate further.